# Why onActivityResult always returns null values for Intent extra

Tags: android, android-intent

My onActivityResult method on activity always returns null for Intent extra. I'm directly calling these methods on activities. please help to find a solution for this.

```
 private void onClickShopNameLayout() {
    shopNameLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(OrderActivity.this,CustomerListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i,CUSTOMER_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
}
```

Starting CustomerListActivity from OrderActivity

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
    Customers customers = customersData.get(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("testing","String value");
    intent.putExtra("selected_customer",customers);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
    finish();
}
```

This is an Interface method from Recycler view Adapter class which triggers on list item click listner. implemented in CustomerListActivity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case CUSTOMER_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                String testing = getIntent().getStringExtra("testing");
                Customers customers = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("selected_customer");
                String businessName = customers.getBusinessName();
                Log.d(TAG,"customer name "+businessName +" testing "+testing);

            }
    }
}
```

onActivityResult override method in OrderActivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onActivityResult()` provides an `Intent` in your code its named as `data`. You should use this `data` instead of `getIntent()` to get intent `extra` values .

**Try this:**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case CUSTOMER_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                String testing = data.getStringExtra("testing");
                Customers customers = data.getParcelableExtra("selected_customer");
                String businessName = customers.getBusinessName();

                Log.d(TAG,"customer name " + businessName +" testing "+testing);
            }
        break; // Don't forget to use break for multiple cases
    }
}
```

Comment: No worries. ..its just a mistake only. Btw If my answer seems useful please give an upvote. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the extras from the activity intent, instead of the activity result intent.

Instead of

```
String testing = getIntent().getStringExtra("testing");
Customers customers = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("selected_customer");
```

do

```
String testing = data.getStringExtra("testing");
Customers customers = data.getParcelableExtra("selected_customer");
```

Answer (score 0):

In case there are more than 2 Activities defined in Application (in Manifest) I had to be specific in Intent when using setResult(result, data).

On your example it would be:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
    Customers customers = customersData.get(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerListActivity.this, OrderActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("testing","String value");
    intent.putExtra("selected_customer",customers);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
    finish();
}
```

And startActivityForResult() is deprecated now. New approach would look like:

```
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mStartForResult = registerForActivityResult(new StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Intent intent = result.getData();
                // Handle the Intent
            }
        }
    });

// and later in the code

mStartForResult.launch(new Intent(this, ResultProducingActivity.class));
```